# Array in JSON not parsing with custom decoding function in Swift

Tags: json, swift

This question might seem similar to other questions with the same title. However, my decodable is in a function called load.

Here is what my JSON file looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1001
      "name": "tempName"
      "item1": [
                  {
                     "id": 1101
                     "element": "tempElement"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 1201
                     "element": "tempElement2"
                  },
               ]
   }
]
```

I've built a `struct temp` to access the information within my JSON file after decoding it. I am not sure if it is extremely relevant but this is what it looks like:

```
struct Temp: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
   var id: Int
   var name: String
   var item1: ExampleItem
}

struct ExampleItem: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable{
   var id: Int
   var element: String
}
```

My structs don't seem too crazy so I assume the problem occurs when I am parsing and decoding my JSON. This is the code I am using

```
let tempData: [Temp] = load("tempData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }
    
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

I think `Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead` bug is occurring when the code tries to decode `item1` because `item1` is an array. What should I change in my load function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JSON is invalid. It should be comma-separated:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1001,
      "name": "tempName",
      "item1": [
                  {
                     "id": 1101,
                     "element": "tempElement"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 1201,
                     "element": "tempElement2"
                  },
               ]
   }
]
```

Then you need to parse `item1` as an array:

```
struct Temp: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
   var id: Int
   var name: String
   var item1: [ExampleItem] // <- declare as an array
}
```

---

Note: I suggest renaming `item1` to `items`. For this you need to use `CodingKeys` (it is as a custom mapping between a model and a JSON):

```
struct Temp: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, items = "item1"
    }
    
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var items: [ExampleItem]
}
```